# how to get content from modem usb inbox and write it to mysql database table

Tags: php, database

For example the message is in this format:

**PDP=222, APC=423, FTC=789**

My database table columns are: **PDP, APC FTC**. I want a script that would copy the value of each column respectively, from the inbox of the modem usb and store it into corresponding column in a database.

For example for **PDP** column it would copy the value assigned to **PDP** form the message (i.e 222) and store it in the database table and do the same for the rest of the columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expode()` and `implode()` functions for that in order to build your query:

```
<?php
    $query = '';
    $qParams = [];
    $qValues = [];
    $message = 'PDP=222, APC=423, FTC=789';
    $arr = explode(',', $message);
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $tmp = explode("=", $value);
        $qParams[] = $tmp[0];
        $qValues[] = $tmp[1];
    }
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO modem_table 
            (" . implode(",", $qParams) . ") 
        VALUES 
            ('" . implode("','", $qValues) . "')";

    echo $query;
?>
```

Output query:

```
INSERT INTO modem_table (PDP, APC, FTC) VALUES ('222','423','789')
```